# How can I install a jailbreak app on an iOS device without a provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing, jailbreak, provisioning

I'd like to be able to build a jailbreak app and test this on my jailbroken iOS device without a proper provisioning profile. Does anyone have any information as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: do you own a mac always a good start

Comment: you should elaborate in steps what you have done...whenever posting a question..look it as from someone else point of view...your question isn't really well explained for anyone to come up with good answer...

Comment: @shubhank I want to know the procedure for installing app on jailbroken app without signing for developer program.

Comment: search google for signing your own provisioning profile..jailbroken

Comment: @DJ can you elaborate on when one might find that? the steps i have found on google do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Buy a mac

Step 2: Sign into [apple developers](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?path=%2F%2Fsubmission%2Fsafari%2F&appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea)

Step 3: [Follow these tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xqn5IHbusA)

How did you not find this information on Google?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. I actually dont want to spend 99$ for developers program. So, I need to know the way to install app on jailbroken iphone. I Hope now I am clear

Comment: @user1237220 I thought you could get the dev kit without paying(ie: you pay for listing on the app store) could be wrong though

Comment: even if I want to test my app on lphone/ipod touch then also i need to pay 99$ but thas not the case with jailbroken device

Answer (score 2):

Please note, that this is a very poorly written question and if you want help in the future, it's always better to explain exactly what you're looking for.

From my understanding, you're wanting the iPhone Toolchain.

Here's the getting started guide

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started

And here's the information you'll need to bypass provisioning profiles.

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile